# Write Farsi in minted environment Latex

Tags: pdftex, minted, overleaf, right-to-left

I'm using overleaf to write my document and I need to list some python code in minted environment that contains Farsi words as follows:

```
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=bg]{python}
>>> farsi_tagged_sents = nltk.corpus.multext_east.tagged_sents("oana-fa.xml", tagset='universal')
>>> farsi_tagged_sents[0]
[('یکی', 'NUM'),
 ('از', 'ADP'),
 ('روزهايِ', 'NOUN'),
 ('بسيار', 'ADV'),
 ('سردِ', 'ADJ'),
 ('ماهِ', 'NOUN'),
 ('آوريل', 'NOUN'),
 ('بود', 'VERB'),
 ('و', 'CONJ'),
 ('ساعتها', 'NOUN'),
 ('سيزده', 'NUM'),
 ('ضربه', 'NOUN'),
 ('مينواختند', 'VERB'),
 ('.', '')]
\end{minted}
```

However, nothing is displayed between quotes when I compile the above code. I tried `babel` package and `\FR{}` command but no luck. Is there any way I could highlight my code and at the same time include Farsi in it?

Comment: Please add a complete code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only realistic way to do this is to use `babel` and `lualatex`.

The bad news is that you say you are using Overleaf. Almost certainly, the version of `babel` on Overleaf is too old for this to work, so you will need to run an up to date TeXLive install locally.

## MWE

Compile this with: `lualatex --shell-escape filename`.

The `mapfont=direction` option allows `babel` to automatically switch to a Persian font for RTL characters. This means there is no need to mark up the text in the `minted` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main,language=Default]{english}
\babelprovide[import,mapfont=direction,language=Default]{persian}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont{sf}{Latin Modern Sans}
\babelfont{tt}{Latin Modern Mono}
\babelfont[persian]{tt}{FreeMono}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\footnotesize]{python}
>>> farsi_tagged_sents = nltk.corpus.multext_east.tagged_sents("oana-fa.xml", tagset='universal')
>>> farsi_tagged_sents[0]
[('یکی', 'NUM'),
 ('از', 'ADP'),
 ('روزهايِ', 'NOUN'),
 ('بسيار', 'ADV'),
 ('سردِ', 'ADJ'),
 ('ماهِ', 'NOUN'),
 ('آوريل', 'NOUN'),
 ('بود', 'VERB'),
 ('و', 'CONJ'),
 ('ساعتها', 'NOUN'),
 ('سيزده', 'NUM'),
 ('ضربه', 'NOUN'),
 ('مينواختند', 'VERB'),
 ('.', '')]
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm. Thank you!